# Until user input matches variable do

Tags: bash, shell, input, compare

Okay, so I'm trying to create a username/password login script of sorts. (may not be the most secure idea I'm still working on it) ;)

My script will load variables to compare to from file like this. (right now I'm just working on password portion)

```
./path/to/variables.conf
```

This file will contain a variable called

```
PASS=SOME_VALUE
```

I plan to use read to obtain the variable that will be compared

```
read -p "Enter your password:" CPASS;
```

Now the part I'm missing (how I envision it working)

```
while "$CPASS" doesn't match "$PASS" do 
read -p "Wrong password, try again:" CPASS;
```

Thank you & any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nice to know I was close :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.  You just need `[ ]` braces and the `!=` operator to [compare strings in bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions):

```
PASS=SOME_VALUE

read -p "Enter your password:" CPASS

while [ "$CPASS" != "$PASS" ]; do 
    read -p "Wrong password, try again:" CPASS
done
```

Also note it would be highly advisable to pass the `-s` parameter to read, so that the entered password is not echoed back to the user.  From the `read` section of `man bash`:

```
          -s     Silent  mode.  If input is coming from a terminal, char-
                 acters are not echoed.
```

Note though that there will also be no newline echoed back to the user when the user hits ENTER, so you'll have to manually insert a newline after every `read` so that lines are properly formatted.  So you should probably replace your read statements with something like this:

```
read -s -p "Enter your password:" CPASS
echo
```

Comment: The you very much! I was just trying  until [[  "$CPASS" -eq "$PASS" ]]; do ,but it failed cause it only accepts integers.

Comment: You can still use `until`; just replace `-eq` with `=`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, `until` could be used here instead of while.  The statement would be something like `until [ "$CPASS" = "$PASS" ]; do`

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, I always use read -s but it doesn't always work for some reason. I script for Android Linux devices and not all of them capable of using the -s option.